# Create a IP address to goto on a computer browser to access an iOS App

Tags: xcode, ios7, ip, wifi

I'm an intermediate iOS developer, and I recently downloaded app called PlayerXtreme.

This app played MP4 files, and you could transfer MP4 files to the app by opening a web browser on your computer and going to `http://192.168.0.4:1234`. Then you could upload your MP4 from the computer and it would show up in the app.

I thought this feature was AMAZING, and I was wondering what it was called, or if someone knew how to recreate this feature. I would describe it as the title, setting up a custom IP to goto on the computer that can *talk* to the app.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Likely what it's doing is setting up a simple webserver on the local IP of the phone (yours just happens to be 192.168.0.4).  Basically running a small webserver on your phone to serve up this UI to upload/download files.

Comment: Can you give me a pointer on how to do this? I'm Googling at this moment.